# is there any way to check the file names obtained from sftp to a table column (which has the filenames) in Pentaho Spoon?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

i have some files uploaded to SFTP and there is a table which has filenames i need to compare both the filenames and process the files which are in common further, in Pentaho Spoon. How should we do it any ideas?
i have tried with database lookup and Modified javascript value, but facing some problems!

Comment: Maybe you should add more information - what have you tried and what problems are you facing ?

Comment: Can you please share your transformation/ job you have tried so far. This will help to understand your full requirement. In short, yes its possible to compare the sftp file before PUT.